# CEFSharp-webRTC not work in WPF,but work in Winform

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm currently working with CefSharp V79.1.360 for WPF (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) ,I'm trying to use browser to show the webRTC,it's not work ,just show the local video,can't show the remote video,but it work in CefSharp V79.1.360 for Winform.my settings is same.
Who can help me?[settings in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9wJn.jpg)

@amaitland ,thank you for your answers,maybe i need show some pictures to you for explain my problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQzCv.png),the chrome show:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T7aA.png)

this testing in winform:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esFBK.png)

Comment: You'll need to wait for the next major version for the `WPF` control. You can use the `WinForms` control in `WPF` using a `WindowsFormsHost`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,I‘ve rollbacked to my last version in CefSharp V59 for WPF,The work returned to normal.I'll waiting for the next major version,may I ask whether the next major version is V81？

Comment: On https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp you can select 'Release Only' under the watch option to be notified.

Comment: Now,i was updated to v83.4.20,it's also not work.so strange

Comment: What are you testing with?

Comment: the platform of wpf,testing the webRTC video function,like:https://solutions.agora.io/education/web/

Comment: Please test with the minimal example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: WebRTC should already be enabled.

Comment: ok，i am download the minimal example,it's also not work,but i try it in chrome which version is 83,it's work normal.

Comment: You can use the pre release of https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost/83.4.20-pre to host the native browser in WPF,  basically the same as using WinForms version.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,when use the pre release,every setting is same the winforms,but show the black like the picture in the question additional information.

Comment: Have you tested on another computer?  I've not seen any other reports of issues

Comment: Yes，i test pc to pc (all in cefsharp platform),it's ok,when test pc to app,it's show the black,but test pc with chrome to app,it's work normal.so i think there has any different setting with chrome